# how can i get the properties of a object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

how can i get the properties of my object?

hello i'm trying to get the properties with the array of ids but my console say undefined

i try with this

> console.log(data.entry.properties)

it show me the two properties "pm:title" and "pm:taggable", but i only want the "pm:taggable" with his array

i try something like

> console.log(data.entry.properties["pm:taggable"])

but it show me: properties of undefined (reading 'cm:taggable')

i´d like to show in console only the the array of ids 'cm:taggable'

```
data: {
    entry: {
      isFile: true,
      createdByUser: [Object],
      content: [Object],
      aspectNames: [Array],
      isFolder: false,
      modifiedByUser: [Object],
      name: 'Cine',
      properties: [Object]
    }
  }
```

the properties have a object with

```
"properties": {
            "pm:title": "Scary movie",
            "pm:taggable": [
                "a112a22463563-9c56-428f-a4ac-a2341as2a",
                "2545ds467-62e5-448d-a062-34sf466dfs",
                "a3af33-2b8d-40c3-98c3-3awfsa356a"
            ],
            "cm:description": "Description"
        }
```

Comment: There are identical properties keys in your JSON2, which is generally not correct

Comment: I changed the code to see if it is better to understand

Comment: Can you try once with `Object.keys(obj)`?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it works for me. Perhaps you are incorrectly referring to the parent element, skipping the variable name?

```js
const resourceData = {
  "data": {
    "entry": {
      "id": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "nodeType": "string",
      "isFolder": true,
      "isFile": true,
      "isLocked": false,
      "modifiedAt": "2022-09-23T18:25:21.236Z",
      "modifiedByUser": {
        "displayName": "string",
        "id": "string"
      },
      "aspectNames": [
        "string"
      ],
      "properties": {},
      "allowableOperations": [
        "string"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "pm:title": "title",
        "pm:taggable": [
          "a112a22463563-9c56-428f-a4ac-a2341as2a",
          "2545ds467-62e5-448d-a062-34sf466dfs",
          "a3af33-2b8d-40c3-98c3-3awfsa356a"
        ],
        "cm:description": "Description"
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(resourceData.data.entry.properties['pm:title'])
console.log(resourceData.data.entry.properties['pm:taggable'])
console.log(resourceData.data.entry.properties['cm:description'])
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but i tried and is not working I changed the code to see if it is better to understand

Comment: To get the output of data: etc, which command did you use? Is it possible to write the entire console.log exactly here?

Comment: console.log(resourceData.data.entry.properties['pm:title'])

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cm:title')

Comment: what result console.data(resourceData)? start with data: .. ?

Comment: `data: {
    entry: {
      isFile: true,
      createdByUser: [Object],
      content: [Object],
      aspectNames: [Array],
      isFolder: false,
      modifiedByUser: [Object],
      name: 'Cine',
      properties: [Object]
    }
  }`

Comment: if i use console.log(resourceData.data.entry.properties) it show me all the properties of the object but i only need to show one

Comment: I update answer for resourceData. But it keeps working!

Comment: If the code in the question doesn't demonstrate the problem, then don't answer it and flag it as not reproducible.

Comment: @gre_gor I understand you! You should not give answers without a guarantee of 100% success. Even if the answer may lead to an idea of how to do it, then you should not do it either. Sometimes, the correct answer makes it possible to understand how to write code, but this is not appreciated here. I heard you, I will adhere to these rules